# What is the difference between PTHREAD_RECURSIVE_MUTEX_INITIALIZER and PTHREAD_RECURSIVE_MUTEX_INITIALIZER_NP?

Tags: c, pthreads

When statically initializing a recursive mutex, what is the difference between

```
static pthread_mutex_t foo_mutex = PTHREAD_RECURSIVE_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

and

```
static pthread_mutex_t foo_mutex = PTHREAD_RECURSIVE_MUTEX_INITIALIZER_NP;
```

and why should I want the one instead of the other?

Comment: Are you sure `PTHREAD_RECURSIVE_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` exists? Haven't found anything about it??

Comment: Indeed, on my Ubuntu linux system, my `/usr/include/pthread.h` file doesn't define the version without `_NP`. But here for example, it is defined: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/ndk/+/5b02cc4c4e80fd6a9ee30e0ad4642122e08a007b/android-ndk-r7/platforms/android-14/arch-x86/usr/include/pthread.h at line 46.

Comment: Well, then it seems to be implementation dependend.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"_NP" is meant as a hint that the feature is nonportable. In order to keep the hint there, you are best off to use the "_NP" version.

Other than that I suspect there is no difference. Not 100% sure, though.