# pthread_recursive_mutex_initializer_np vs pthread_mutex_initializer

Tags: mutex, recursive-mutex

Other than the answer given in [What is the difference between PTHREAD_RECURSIVE_MUTEX_INITIALIZER and PTHREAD_RECURSIVE_MUTEX_INITIALIZER_NP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636850/what-is-the-difference-between-pthread-recursive-mutex-initializer-and-pthread-r)

I would like to know what are the other differences between these two.

Comment: Posix does not define `PTHREAD_RECURSIVE_MUTEX_INITIALIZER`, so you have to specify where you found it.

Comment: Look at my question title, I've mentioned pthread_mutex_initializer.

Comment: Your title says one thing, your question says another.